# Вывести ID в запрос к БД через цикл

Tags: php, sql, циклы

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Выглядит это так: есть стена, к ней разные люди оставляют записи (Таблицы users и wall). Переменная $getwall получает все записи к стене конкретного пользователя, я через цикл foreach вывожу все эти записи на каждую из стен, но вместе с записями нужно выводить и аватар юзера, который находится в таблицы users. Через inner join сделал объединение (Если просто подставить ID где нибудь в воркбенче, то нужный аватар выводится и код работает), пытаюсь вывести это уже на сайте, в итоге место, начиная с которого должен выводится аватар просто игнорируется.

Если убрать этот момент:

> getObject("SELECT users.avatar FROM users INNER JOIN wall
>   ON users.id=wall.$item->users_id"); ?>

То соответственно цикл работает. Прошу помощи, идеи уже как это сделать иссякли.

```html
  <?php if (count($getwall) > 0) : ?>
          <?php foreach ($getwall as $item) : ?>

      <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
       <img src="../<?php $db->getObject("SELECT users.avatar FROM users INNER JOIN wall ON users.id=wall.$item->users_id"); ?>" width="100px" height="100px" style="border: 1px solid gray">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-left: 5px">

        <b>
        <?= $item->author ?>

        <?= $item->date ?>
        </b>
        <br>
        <span style="text-align:right;">
        <?= $item->text ?>
        </span>

      </div>
      <?php endforeach ?>
      <?php else : ?>
      <em>Микроблог пуст! Будь первым!</em>
      <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заключай сложные переменные в фигурные скобки, иначе интерпретатор не может понять что где:

```
"SELECT users.avatar FROM users INNER JOIN wall ON users.id=wall.{$item->users_id}"
```

также я не уверен, что нужна `wall.` перед `$item->users_id`, т.к. это скорее всего обычное число, а не имя колонки в таблице `wall`

Стоит немного посмотреть в доки для ознакомления: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

Comment: Благодарю, даже не думал, что все на столько просто. (.wall) действительно оказал без надобности.

Comment: @Bek1zo Почитай еще варианты в доках: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php